# Laravel - Eager Load Single Item in a ManyToMany Realtionship

Tags: php, laravel

In Laravel, is it possible to Eager Load the 'first' item from a `BelongsToMany` relationship?  As in, return an `Item` from that relationship, rather than a `Collection`?

From what i've tried (and read) applying `first()` or `limit('1')` or any other constraint will not return an individual Item

Comment: Can you post your code please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use an [accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators).

I guess you need something like `latest`, `first`, or such kind of single item from a collection, so you can do this:

```
public function items()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany(Item::class);
}

public function getLatestItemAttribute()
{
  return $this->items->sortByDesc('created_at')->first();
}
```

then you can simply use:

```
$yourModel->latestItem; // single related model OR null
```

---

Edit: as mentioned by @Hkan in the comment, the above code will result in fetching whole collection and working on it. That said, you can use alternatively relation object and directly query the table:

```
public function getLatestItemAttribute()
{
  return $this->items()->latest()->first();
}
```

however, this way you run the query whenever you call `$model->latestItem`. As a result you get a **new copy** of the model, not the same instance, and obviously you can query your database arbitrary number of times, depending on your use-case.

**The hard, but best** way would be to mimic the relationship:

```
public function getLatestItemAttribute()
{
  if (!$this->relationLoaded('latestItem')) {
    $this->setRelation('latestItem', $this->items()->latest()->first());
  }

  return $this->getRelation('latestItem');
}
```

in this case `$model->latestItem` is treated like any other *single* relationship, once loaded. That is, it will be single instance whenever you call the accessor and will be saved when using `push` method.

Comment: That would fetch all the related items. What it should be instead is `return $this->items()->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->first()`.

Comment: yes, it would. However, whether it **should** be or not depends on the requirements. Edit for more info.

Comment: whoa! Didn't know about that `setRelation()` method. Looks pretty cool.

Comment: hm thats very interesting! Definitely didn't know you could do that!

Answer (score 0):

@djt
I was looking also for a solution where I can `eager load relationship with only one item`, and tried everything, and it seems there is no such solution except `joins`

```
Collection::select('items.item_name as name', 'items_sub.sub_name as subname')
->leftJoin('items_sub', function ($join) {
    $join->on('items.id', '=', 'items_sub.item_id')->where('items_sub.type', '=', 0);
})->get();
```

This way you get all `Collection function helpers`
And also it reduce the amount of queries you make to DB,
Because when you `eager load with Eloquent` it make **at least 2 queries to DB**
I've added `where` jsut as example.